# Solving a double integral with infinite bounds with a set of rules on a function with two variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, functions

Here's the problem description:

Let the function $f(x,y)$ be defined by

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 g(x)/x,&\text{if}\, 0 < y < x\\
 0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

where $g(x)$ is a non-negative function defined on $(0, \infty)$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ $g(x) dx = 1$.

Compute
  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ $f(x,y)dx dy$

I swear this should be pretty easy but for some reason I'm just stumped. I tried integration first with respect to $dx$ and splitting up the improper integral on the inside from $-\infty$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\infty$... but I just ended up with something that I couldn't really compute.

I'm also not really sure how I'm supposed to use the fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ $g(x) dx = 1$ when I have to integrate $g(x)/x$. I'm guessing I'm pretty rusty on my calc.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Observe that
$$
\int_0^x (g(x)/x)\,dy=(g(x)/x)\cdot1\Bigr|_0^x=g(x).
$$
Let $D=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq y\}$. Then
$$
\int\int_{D}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx=1.
$$

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot of sense! But I'm having some trouble actually getting to that step. How would I end up with the bounds $0$ to $x$? Because I'm splitting up the integral on the inside from $-\infty$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\infty$. The $-\infty$ to $0$ part is just equal to $0$, but then I have an integral from $0$ to $\infty$. The good thing now is that I'm integrating with respect to dy, though.

Comment: @Kawaiiii The actual domain of integration is `an infinite triangle` $\{(x,y):0<y<x,0<x<\infty$ and every integral with respect to $y$ gives $g(x)$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm really sorry but I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how every integral with respect to $y$ gives $g(x)$... I get that the domain is an infinite triangle in the first quadrant, but how does that lead to the first statement?

Comment: @Kawaiiii Is the extended hint enough?

Comment: So we're integrating over the region D, with D being an infinite triangle in the first quadrant, but how do we get from that double integral to $\int_0^\infty g(x)\,dx$?... I'm so sorry if I'm being dumb, something just isn't clicking for me for some reason...

Comment: @Kawaiiii The inner integral is $\int_0^x (g(x)/x)\,dy$ and was computed as a first version of the hint.

Comment: Ohhhh, wow I see it now! That helps a lot. So, from the original post, could I just say that because $f(x,y)$ is only non-zero from $0$ to $\infty$, and because $0 < y < x$, then I could let $D=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq y\}$ (as you said), and just "convert" the integral from $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ $f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ to $\int\int_{D}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ ?

Comment: @Kawaiiii Yes. :-)